# With New MyTestableMacro .Run - What does it do?

Tags: vba, rubberduck

I am following [this](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/19/how-to-unit-test-vba-code/) tutorial by RubberduckVBA and have come across this piece of code, but have no idea what it really does:

```
With New MyTestableMacro
    .Run dataServiceStub, wsServiceStub
End With
```

I have tried to search for *"New keyword in With statement"* as well as a few other things, but do not find anything about it.

It is not code that I have seen in a year of doing VBA...

I have also tried making a class named `MyTestableMacro` with a method `Run` which also did not work.

Just to be clear, I want to know what `MyTestableMacro` is. Is it a class, module, temporary Macro? And is the Run A method/function inside of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, this is no different from the following code:

```
Dim something As MyTestableMacro
Set something = New MyTestableMacro
With something
    ...
End With
```

Note that we had to `Dim` a variable, then initialize it with the `New` keyword. But we can cut out the 2 extra lines by compressing them into this single statement:

```
With New MyTestableMacro
    ...
End With
```

In regards to your another question -- the `MyTestableMacro` ought to be a class module. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to `New` it at all. And the `Run` typically would be a `Public` method (could be a `Sub` or a `Function`, given the syntax used in your post). A `Private` method would not work. `Friend` would work only for within the same VBA project but it's very rare to see a method using `Friend` instead of `Public` or `Private`.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the answer I was looking for. I thought it had something to do with cutting out a few lines of code, but was not completely sure about it. The class question was actually not useful information now that I look back at it.

Comment: @AlfaBravo it makes the `With` block variable be held by the `With` block itself; an object is created with the `New` keyword, its reference "belongs" to the `With` block, and when execution reaches `End With` the object gets destroyed. You can verify this by putting `Debug.Print` statements in the `Class_Initialize` and `Class_Terminate` handlers of the class module, e.g. `Debug.Print "hello"` in `Class_Initialize`, then `Debug.Print "goodbye"` in `Class_Terminate` and then `Debug.Print "doing the work"` in the `Run` method.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks, this is actually another helpful thing I have learned today.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, Could you clarify in your tutorial that the `MyTestableMacro` ought to be a class module, as you put it?

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson I would, except I'm not sure which part of "What if we introduced a class, and moved the functionality into there?" and "we can pull out the dependencies and unit-test the MyTestableMacro class" is unclear about this... how do you suggest I make it even clearer?

Comment: Change the sentence to say "Now we'd be looking at this *class*..."